# Update Cimg images and display from call back functions

Tags: c++, cimg

I'm writing some C++ code to display the images got from a camera. In the code, a call-back function will be called by the camera every time a new image comes through and I'll get a pointer in memory where the image is stored. Now I want to use CImg to display the image every time it gets through(like a video) and possibly use functions in CImg to manipulate the image.

I was thinking of defining the Cimg instance from the pointer in the call back function and send the pointer of CImg display to the call back function. So every time the callback function is called, the instance is overwritten then the new image is displayed.

```cpp
struct data {
    CImgDisplay* disp;
};


int callBack(int Nimg, data *pointersPassedIn){
    auto   disp = pointersPassedIn->disp;
    int   width,height;
    getParameter(WIDTH, &width);//Retrieve height and width of the image from camera
    getParameter(HEIGHT, &height);
    unsigned short* imgPtr = (unsigned short*)getImagePtr(Nimg);//Retrieve image pointer from camera, as 16-bit image, use unsigned short
    CImg <unsigned short> img(imgPtr ,width,height);
    disp->render(img);
    disp->paint();
    return 0 ;
};

int main(){
    int width,height;
    getParameter(WIDTH, &width);
    getParameter(HEIGHT, &height);
    CImgDisplay disp(width,height);
    registerCallBack(&disp);//will add &disp to struct data and send it to call back function
    aquire();
    while (!disp.is_closed()){
        ;
    }
    stopAquire();
};
```

However, only one image is displayed, then the program quit itself.

Thank you

Comment: Well, you only aquire one image and display this until the window is closed. Try doing that inside the loop i.e. fetch the image, and update the display.
Actually, you might want to make that multi-threaded: Keep a thread with the GUI dsplaying the current image, and make the fetching, processing etc in another thread, which delivers the final image to the GUI thread.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If the code works correctly (if I don't define the CImg instance and display in my call back), the camera calls the callback functions multiple times (at 3fps) and I can see it because I made the call back function print to console every time it is called. But with the Cimg instance defined, the program quits at the second call to the callback function. Also, thank you for the multi-threaded suggestion, I don't know how to do that, but I will list it as my future study.

Comment: Hm, okay. I just saw that in your callback `image` is actually undefine and that `ìmg` ist not used at all. Please correct that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Corrected.

Comment: Alright. The documentation for `CImgDisplay` says "Should not be used for common CImgDisplay uses, since display() is more useful." This does not solve your problem, but make the code shorter and shorter code is in general more bug-free than longer code ;)

Comment: Do you mean the display() method of the CImg object? It is great if I can use that, but every call to .display() ends up with a new window of one image, and the program sleeps until that image window is closed... But thank you for the advice.